# Which Desktop Environment will give me a UI bar like this?

Tags: desktop, desktop-environment

I really like this style of taskbar. I've been using it for 15+ years (since windows 2000?) and I just like it.

**Left side:**

[image]

**Right side:**

[image]

I briefly tried creating this layout with Cinnamon but was not successful.

Is there a desktop environment that is stable and fast that will let me configure it so the bottom bar looks and feels like a double-height windows taskbar with quick launch icons?

Thanks!

Comment: Xfce can be configured for 2 or more rows, but i'm afraid just the rows of shortcuts among themselves and beside them the rows of window-buttons among themselves. -- maybe you can build yourself something like that with a panel and a dock atop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using [Mate](http://mate-desktop.org/) and two panels across the bottom.  It's not identical (the "start" button and System Tray aren't double-height), but it's the best I've been able to find.